# Unknown error when working with JSON, php and Android

Tags: php, android, json, httphandler, jsonobjectrequest

I've been learning how to use php and JSON with Android and I'm trying to read SQL data with PHP into JSON then to Android. What are my errors?

PHP

```
<?php  
//PDO is a extension which  defines a lightweight, consistent interface for     accessing databases in PHP.  
$db=new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;','root','');  
//here prepare the query for analyzing, prepared statements use less resources and thus run faster  
$row=$db->prepare('select * from drinks');  

$row->execute();//execute the query  
$json_data=array();//create the array  
foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop  
{  
$json_array['drinks_id']=$rec['drinks_id'];  
    $json_array['drink_name']=$rec['drink_name'];  
    $json_array['Description']=$rec['Description'];    
//here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);  

}  

//built in PHP function to encode the data in to JSON format  
//print_r($json_array);
echo json_encode($json_data);  
?>
```

JSON outputted (Sample)

```
{
"0":{
  "drinks_id":"1",
  "drink_name":"Uprising Treason West Coast IPA",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"1":{
  "drinks_id":"2",
  "drink_name":"Flying Dog Snake Dog IPA",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"2":{
  "drinks_id":"3",
  "drink_name":"Crafty Dan 13 Guns America IPA",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"3":{
  "drinks_id":"4",
  "drink_name":"Sixpoint Resin Double IPA",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"4":{
  "drinks_id":"5",
  "drink_name":"Sixpoint Bengali IPA",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"5":{
  "drinks_id":"6",
  "drink_name":"ShipYard ",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"6":{
  "drinks_id":"7",
  "drink_name":"Blue Moon Belgian White ",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"7":{
  "drinks_id":"8",
  "drink_name":"BrewDog Punk IPA ",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"8":{
  "drinks_id":"9",
  "drink_name":"Lagunitas IPA",
  "Description":"Beer"
},
"9":{
  "drinks_id":"10",
  "drink_name":"Brooklyn Larger ",
  "Description":"Larger"
},
"10":{
  "drinks_id":"11",
  "drink_name":"Hazy Hog Cloudy English Cider ",
  "Description":"Cider"
},
"11":{
  "drinks_id":"12",
  "drink_name":"Angry Orchard ",
  "Description":"Cider"
},
"12":{
  "drinks_id":"13",
  "drink_name":"Aspall Suffolk Cyder ",
  "Description":"Cider"
},
"13":{
  "drinks_id":"14",
  "drink_name":"Devils Backbone ",
  "Description":"Cider"
},
"14":{
  "drinks_id":"15",
  "drink_name":"Carlsburg",
  "Description":""
},
"15":{
  "drinks_id":"16",
  "drink_name":"Foster' s",
  "Description":""
},
"16":{
  "drinks_id":"17",
  "drink_name":"Carling ",
  "Description":""
},
"17":{
  "drinks_id":"18",
  "drink_name":"Coors Light",
  "Description":""
},
"18":{
  "drinks_id":"19",
  "drink_name":"Tuborg ",
  "Description":""
},
"19":{
  "drinks_id":"20",
  "drink_name":"Stella Artois",
  "Description":""
},
"20":{
  "drinks_id":"21",
  "drink_name":"San Miguel ",
  "Description":""
},
"21":{
  "drinks_id":"22",
  "drink_name":"Kronenbourg 1664",
  "Description":""
},
"22":{
  "drinks_id":"23",
  "drink_name":"Heineken",
  "Description":""
},
"23":{
  "drinks_id":"24",
  "drink_name":"Birra Moretti",
  "Description":""
},
"24":{
  "drinks_id":"25",
  "drink_name":"Tsingtao",
  "Description":""
},
"25":{
  "drinks_id":"26",
  "drink_name":"Erdinger",
  "Description":""
},
"26":{
  "drinks_id":"27",
  "drink_name":"Tsyskie Gronie",
  "Description":""
},
"27":{
  "drinks_id":"28",
  "drink_name":"Krombacher Pils",
  "Description":""
},
"28":{
  "drinks_id":"29",
  "drink_name":"Tucher Helles Hefe Weizen",
  "Description":""
},
"29":{
  "drinks_id":"30",
  "drink_name":"Newcastle Brown Ale",
  "Description":""
},
"30":{
  "drinks_id":"31",
  "drink_name":"Efes ",
  "Description":""
},
"31":{
  "drinks_id":"32",
  "drink_name":"Baltika 7",
  "Description":""
},
"32":{
  "drinks_id":"33",
  "drink_name":"Devils Backbone",
  "Description":""
},
"33":{
  "drinks_id":"34",
  "drink_name":"Sharps Doom Bar",
  "Description":""
},
"34":{
  "drinks_id":"35",
  "drink_name":"Green King IPA",
  "Description":""
},
"35":{
  "drinks_id":"36",
  "drink_name":"Abbot Ale",
  "Description":""
},
"36":{
  "drinks_id":"37",
  "drink_name":"John Smiths",
  "Description":""
},
 "37":{
  "drinks_id":"38",
  "drink_name":"Guinness",
  "Description":""
}
}
```

Main Activity

```
    package northampton.josh.pubapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Menu";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://192.168.0.11:80/Pub%20crud/GetDrinks4.php";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> drinkList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, TAG + ":Menu Started");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createMenuButtons();
        Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to connect ");
        drinkList = new ArrayList<>();
        new GetDrinks().execute();

    }


    //Add buttons to the menu bar to allow navigation between pages
    private void createMenuButtons() {
        //Get the layout on the left hand side
        LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        //Get the style for the buttons
        ContextThemeWrapper menuStyle = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.menuButton);

        Button customer = new Button(menuStyle);
        customer.setText("Customer");
        customer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Customer.class));
            }
        });
    Button staff = new Button(menuStyle);
    staff.setText("Bar");
    staff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Staff.class));
        }
    });

    Button manager = new Button(menuStyle);
    manager.setText("Manager");
    manager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Manager.class));
        }
    });

    Button settings = new Button(menuStyle);
    settings.setText("Settings");
    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class));
        }
    });

    menu.addView(customer);
    menu.addView(staff);
    menu.addView(manager);
    menu.addView(settings);
}



private class GetDrinks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                // Getting JSON Array node

                JSONArray drinks = jsonObj.getJSONArray("0");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = drinks.getJSONObject(i);

                    String drinks_id = c.getString("drinks_id");
                    String drink_name = c.getString("drink_name");
                    String Description = c.getString("Description");


                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> drink = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    drink.put("drinks_id", drinks_id);
                    drink.put("drink_name", drink_name);
                    drink.put("Description", Description);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    drinkList.add(drink);

                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

HTTP Handler

```
package northampton.josh.pubapp;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Josh on 30/01/2017.
 */

public class HttpHandler {


        private static final String TAG = "Menu";// HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();


        public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
            String response = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                // read the response
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                response = convertStreamToString(in);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return response;
        }

        private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append('\n');

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add at least one sencente about your problem? Which part isn't working?

Comment: I belive its in the main activity when the object is created.  Thats when the program usually has an error displaying wrong data types or something